# Table Design in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to create one table, 
Description : I need to create table based on schedule like daily, weekly & monthly,

Columns are  like : sno, startdate, enddate, day, scheduletype

For example I'll take weekly data,
for my point of view : From sunday to saturday (1 - 7 )Id i create....
So lots of possibilities are creates like (1,2)(1,3) ..(1,2,3)....up to n....this twice possibility only but that will created up to 7 possibility in one.

So how can I store this possibility in mysql database?

If any one have an issue get back to me...

Answer (score 1):

mysql> CREATE TABLE Date (StartDate date, EndDate date,
    -> Number of days VARCHAR(20), Reason(1));
with this you can create a table

Comment: Her problem is not that simple as you are thinking. :)

Comment: Number od combinations are there.....That's why udaya.....if you have any questions let me know